# Formula for Quadrilateral area

Tags: java, math, geometry

I do not find formula for determination of area of Quadrilateral with four vertices (points). Who is strong in math and can help with Java formula for it. Thanks very much.
I know only that 'convex quadrilaterals are divided into two triangles by any of their diagonals'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having vertices coordinates we can calculate are of any polygon using [shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula)

Java code [from here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/area-of-a-polygon-with-given-n-ordered-vertices/)

```
public static double polygonArea(double X[], double Y[], int n)
{
    // Initialize area
    double area = 0.0;
 
    // Calculate value of shoelace formula
    int j = n - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        area += (X[j] + X[i]) * (Y[j] - Y[i]);
         
        // j is previous vertex to i
        j = i;
    }
 
    // Return absolute value
    return Math.abs(area / 2.0);
}
```

For specific case of quadrilateral we can write result without loops

```
Area = 0.5 * ((x[0]*y[1]+x[1]*y[2]+x[2]*y[3]+x[3]*y[0]) - 
              (x[1]*y[0]+x[2]*y[1]+x[3]*y[2]+x[0]*y[3]))
```